# How to configure thread names for multiprocessing.BaseManager instances

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

There's some usage of these BaseManager types in some code I'm debugging.
https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.managers.BaseManager

```py
from multiprocessing.managers import BaseManager
```

The log configuration for our process has the thread name expressed using the standard [record attribute](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logrecord-attributes) `%(threadName)s`.

This results in the typical indexed format you find in multithreaded log traces from threads that do not get names ascribed to them

```
BaseManager-15|MainProcess
BaseManager-17|MainProcess
BaseManager-38|MainProcess
```

Is there a way to get threads under a BaseManager to have their thread name specified?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the implementation for the `managers.py` source there may be something possible under the member `_process`, possibly through the `_ctx` entity

```py
        # spawn process which runs a server
        self._process = self._ctx.Process(
            target=type(self)._run_server,
            args=(self._registry, self._address, self._authkey,
                  self._serializer, writer, initializer, initargs),
            )
        ident = ':'.join(str(i) for i in self._process._identity)
        self._process.name = type(self).__name__  + '-' + ident
        self._process.start()
```

https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/27e59afa2ad98e6bfe26c6b2b7f6294fa561680c/Lib/multiprocessing/managers.py#L561